# play 2.1.5 framework scala : Defining and accessing Global variables

Tags: playframework-2.0, global-variables

I am trying to define a few variables that'll be available in all my app controllers.

I thus followed the steps in Play 2 doc to define a global settings object.

This part seems ok but then i can never access those variables inside a controller.

Here is the code i use to initialize those global variables :

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
    val name = "My name"
}
```

In this file $ROOT/app/Global.scala

Then is in controller $ROOT/app/controllers/Application.scala i call :

```
Global.name
```

And i get a :

```
not found: value Global
```

If anyone has an idea !

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Classes that are placed in the root package in Scala (and Java) cannot be accessed by classes that are outside of the root package. You need to either put your global variables somewhere else and initialize those from Global or move global to a package you can reach and change your application config to point to where you placed it:

```
application.global=my.package.Global
```